# Is there a "short_description" method for variables in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a long variable name in one of my models "xxxx_xxxx_xx_xxxxxxxx" is there an equivilent of:

```
xxxx_xxxx_xx_xxxxxxxx.short_description = 'xxxx'
```

for variables or do I have to make a method to display that? I would like to not have to use a method because I want to be able to sort by this variable in the Django admin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [verbose field name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) option. It allows you use whatever name you like in the admin. There is also the [verbose_name_plural](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options) for *model names* that have unusual plural construxions.